# git checkout . или git reset --hard

Tags: git

Я работаю с `git` и хочу понять, как лучше сбросить изменения, если они мне больше не нужны.

Допустим, я переключился на какую-то ветку, что-то поделал, но потом оказалось, что эти изменения мне не нужны. Я не хочу их `припрятывать`, я хочу от них избавиться, совсем, чтобы, к примеру, переключиться на другую ветку.

Поэксперементировав с различными вариантами, я понял, что можно сделать так:

```
git reset --hard
```

Как я понял, если после `--hard` не указан коммит, то данная команда просто сбрасывает все изменения, возвращаясь к исходному состоянию активного коммита.

Еще можно сделать так:

```
git checkout .
```

Найти точное описание происходящего в этом случае я не смог. Но по наблюдаемым эффектам, я пришел к выводу, что данная команда просто отбрасывает все изменения.

Что же лучше использовать для отбрасывания изменений?

Comment: reset удаляет коммит. если вы коммитнули - reset, если еще нет - checkout

Comment: `git reset --hard` без параметров вроде бы просто возвращается к последнему коммиту. Разве нет?

Comment: @MGNeo, ```git reset --hard``` - очистить область подготовленных изменений, которые войдут в следующий коммит. ```git clean -r -d``` - удалить все файлы и папки, не добавленные в область подготовленных изменений. После этих двух команд  указатель HEAD будет содержать указатель на последний коммит текущей ветки и репозиторий не будет содержать "лишних" файлов/папок